# C# free Doc 2 PDF solution

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ms-office, doc

would anyone suggest a free solution to **programmatically** convert Office documents (mostly .doc) to PDF in the form of a .NET library or a command-line application i can call from my program? Thanks

***PS***: I know I can use SaveAs PDF in newer versions of Office, but some of the clients where the program will run still have older versions of Office.

Comment: Have you considered using office automation, as there is a free download, to add support to save as PDF from Office 2007 applications

Comment: Is this for a web application or forms/service/wpf something?

Comment: it is for a form application, but it has to be invisible to the user

Answer (score 1):

Won't [GhostScript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/reviews/) ([GhostScript Website](http://www.ghostscript.com/)) do that for you? Otherwise, I think, under reserves, that [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/) might do it. If these won't do, I hope that this one will: [PDFCreate](http://www.pdf995.com/faq_dev.html). In fact, after a closer look, if Ghostcript won't do, I would perhaps consider trying PDFCreate as it provides some sample code on the wbesite I linked for it.

You might also want to consult Wikipedia on the topic: [List of PDF software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software)

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use something like PrimoPDF which basically installs a printer that when you print to it, creates a PDF document.  I've never actually called it command line but since it's just another printer, any standard print code would work.

Cody